XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.（WSL2+Ubuntu22.04）
My enviroment is in WSL2-Ubuntu22.04,and I want to use minigrid and mujoco with pygame for some RL experiences show.I already intalled the Vrsrc and sucessfully show zhe xeyes.But when I run my code,it always show the error:
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
and the total process:
enter image description here
and I have setted the XDG_RUNTIME_DIR:
enter image description here
It still have this error..
ask big shots for help
as above
and I have setted the XDG_RUNTIME_DIR: enter image description here It still have this error.. ask big shots for help
